# How to integrate wit.ai With my own chatbot application

Tags: wit.ai

I would like to create my own web chatbot and i like to integrate my app with wit.ai for natural language classification.I need to know how to integrate wit.ai service(**through api call**) with my application(any language in backend).i am using C# in front end.I have gone through the integration part Which  posted in wit.ai website.But i don't know how to connect it .Could anyone send me a **integration details little briefly**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the short answer is its similar to how you would call any other APIs from your application server components. Wit exposes multiple APIs like message, speech and converse which you can call by passing the Authorization token and other payloads and make use of the API response in your application.

- You can use message API if you are only interested in extracting
  intent and other atributes of the sententense
- Use speech for building voice based application and
- Converse if you want to build a little more smarter app. Currently you can only pass text for converse APIs.Hoping they will introduce voice option for this soon.

Now to make things simpler, they have also provided SDKs in various languages like node-wit, pywit etc. So if you want to build your server side logic using on nodejs or python you can use these SDKs. The advantage is that you dont have to manage raw APIs calls and instead it is all managed by SDK. Also, other big advantage is that you can make use of runActions method which encapsulates converse API and make things simpler. If you want to build in nodejs then the messenger example is a good starting point. You can borrow all this logic/concept in your app and replace FB related calls etc with your custom bot. For Python you can look at the below link

https://github.com/wit-ai/pywit/pull/55

Also, you can explore the options like using other frameworks like botkit if you plan to integrate wit with other chatbots like FB messenger or slackbot as these frameworks provide more flexibility and ability to easily  switch to different chatbots in future. But they don't seem to properly support the converse API of wit.

You are specifically looking for integration details. Since you are using c# for frontend app, natuarally the best option would be to use c# for backend as well. In which case you will be left with directly calling wit APIs from your backend as I think there are no SDKs in c#. If you want to make use of SDK in node or python etc then you will have to build a rest based backend (for example) which can be invoked from your c# application. I am currently working on a nodejs app and integrating it with wit using node-wit. I can share some code once its ready but i dont know when I will be able to finish it. For bootstrapping my application I have used [this](https://github.com/amirrajan/pomodoro-text) node application. If you have some understanding of node then you can look at the /server/controllers logic. Similar to this application I have built a witController which uses runAction to interact with wit and I am calling this from front-end when user submits a message to your bot. The biggest challenge in runAction is to figure-out a way to send back the wit response to your front-end and get follow up response from user. Wit sends the response in Send method as you can see in the node-wit's messanger example.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for your Crystal clear explanation.